# How to use the "include" keyword in the "CMS Connect" tool's path (WordPress API)

Tags: experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

I'm trying to load a list of posts from a WordPress API into an Experience Cloud site using the "CMS Connect" tool.

Does anyone know how I can use the **"include"** keyword  in the path of this request?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer to my question and would like to share it with you in case someone runs into this issue in the future.

Here are the paths I had to set for CONTENT ITEM and the CONTENT LIST:

CONTENT ITEM path: **wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{component}**

CONTENT LIST path: **wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1490&include=**